Slidable: How to close a slidable by tapping anywhere on the screen?
Is there a solution to close a slidable by tapping anywhere on the screen automatically instead of doing it manually?, as example i have this code :
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_slidable/flutter_slidable.dart';

    void main() => runApp(const MyApp());
    
    class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
      const MyApp({
        super.key,
      });
    
      @override
      State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
    }
    
    class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
      late final controller = SlidableController(this);
    
      // Define a list of items
      final List<String> items = List.generate(10, (index) => 'Item $index');
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          title: 'Slidable Example',
          home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Slidable List Example')),
            body: SlidableAutoCloseBehavior(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  const Text(
                    "HELLO",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50),
                  ),
                  Flexible(
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: items.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return Slidable(
                          key: ValueKey(index),
                          startActionPane: ActionPane(
                            motion: const ScrollMotion(),
                            children: [
                              SlidableAction(
                                onPressed: (context) => editItem(context, index),
                                backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF21B7CA),
                                foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                                icon: Icons.edit,
                                label: 'Edit',
                              ),
                              SlidableAction(
                                onPressed: (context) => deleteItem(index),
                                backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFFE4A49),
                                foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                                icon: Icons.delete,
                                label: 'Delete',
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          endActionPane: ActionPane(
                            motion: const ScrollMotion(),
                            children: [
                              SlidableAction(
                                onPressed: (context) =>
                                    controller.openEndActionPane(),
                                backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF7BC043),
                                foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                                icon: Icons.archive,
                                label: 'Archive',
                              ),
                              SlidableAction(
                                onPressed: (context) => controller.close(),
                                backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF0392CF),
                                foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                                icon: Icons.save,
                                label: 'Save',
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          child: ListTile(title: Text(items[index])),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    
      // Method to handle item editing
      void editItem(BuildContext context, int index) {
        // For demonstration, showing a simple dialog to edit item
        showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) {
            final TextEditingController controller =
                TextEditingController(text: items[index]);
            return AlertDialog(
              title: const Text('Edit Item'),
              content: TextField(
                controller: controller,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText: 'Enter new value'),
              ),
              actions: [
                TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      items[index] = controller.text;
                    });
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                  child: const Text('Save'),
                ),
              ],
            );
          },
        );
      }
    
      // Method to handle item deletion
      void deleteItem(int index) {
        setState(() {
          items.removeAt(index);
        });
      }
    } 

in this code i need to close the slidable even when tapping oustide the list, on "HELLO" as example.

It can be done using the TapRegion widget.
You first need to create a SlidableController for every Slidable:
late List<SlidableController> _controllers;

@override
  void initState() {
     _controllers = List.generate(10, (index) => SlidableController(this));
    super.initState();
  }

Assign a controller to each Slidable based on index:
return Slidable(
  key: ValueKey(index),
  controller: _controllers[index],
...

Now create a method that will close a Slidable:
  void closeSlidable(int index) {
    final controller = _controllers[index];
    controller.close();
  }

And finally, wrap the Slidable in a TapRegion:
return TapRegion(
  onTapOutside: (_) => closeSlidable(index),
  child: Slidable(
    key: ValueKey(index),
    controller: _controllers[index],

Note: you may need to manually manage the SlideController list if you want the user to be able to add new Slidables.
